# Numbering lines awk script

Tags: awk

How can I number the following input using awk script.

```
30.67
30.89
31.65
32.23
33.44
34.11
34.34
35.09
36.65
37.30
38.22
39.08
40.55
41.43
41.99
42.21
43.00
44.33
45.50
46.44
47.90
48.09
49.44
49.54
50.76
```

The expected out put will be:

```
0.67
0.89
1.65
2.23
3.44
4.11
4.34
5.09
6.65
7.30
8.22
9.08
10.55
11.43
11.99
12.21
13.00
14.33
15.50
16.44
17.90
18.09
19.44
19.54
20.76
```

These data are the second field in the lines/Record

that means for example :
first line look like

```
 a 30.67 b joy 
 b 30.89 x  joey
 ...
```

and the out put:

```
 a 0.67 b joy 
 b 0.89 x joey
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: It is not very clear. Given XX.YY, will it always be `XX-30.YY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk '{$2=sprintf("%.2f",$2-30)}7' file
```

this handles the case like `30.00`, it will ouput `0.00` instead of `0`.